# TypeError: signInMutation.mutate is not a function when using createApi from @reduxjs/toolkit/query/react

Tags: reactjs, next.js, redux-toolkit

So I am creating a twitter clone for practice. I am trying to fetch the data from the server with **username** and **password**. However, I am receiving the error that states:

`TypeError: signInMutation.mutate is not a function at handleSubmit (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./app/components/authentification/sign-in/SignInForm.tsx:28:51) at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19449:14) at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackImpl (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19498:16) at invokeGuardedCallback (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19573:29) at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19587:25) at executeDispatch (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:30622:3) at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:30654:7) at processDispatchQueue (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:30667:5) at dispatchEventsForPlugins (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:30678:3) at eval (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:30868:12) at batchedUpdates$1 (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23765:12) at batchedUpdates (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27584:12) at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:30867:3) at dispatchEvent (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:28640:5) at dispatchDiscreteEvent (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:28611:5)`

I have tried using chatGPT to help me identify the path to the correct solution, however my attempts failed. See the component code below:

```
import {
  Button,
  TextField,
  Link,
  Grid,
  Box,
} from '@mui/material'
import { useSignInMutation } from '@/app/api/postApiSlice';

interface SignInProps {
  onSwitchToSignUp: () => void;
  onClose: () => void;
}

export const SignInForm: React.FC<SignInProps> = ({ onSwitchToSignUp, onClose }) => {

  const signInMutation = useSignInMutation()

  const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
  const signInData = {
    username: formData.get('username') as string,
    password: formData.get('password') as string,
  };

  try {
    const { data } = await (signInMutation as any).mutate(signInData);
    console.log('Success!', data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    throw new Error("Failed to sign in. Check your credentials.");
  }
  onClose();
};

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        marginTop: 5,
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}
    >
      <h1 className='text-2xl'>Sign In to Twitter</h1>
      <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <>
          <TextField
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="email"
            name="email"
            autoComplete="email"
            autoFocus
            label="Email"
          />
          <TextField
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            name="password"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            autoComplete="current-password"
            InputProps={{
              sx: {
                "& input": {
                  color: 'gray'
                }
              }
            }}
            placeholder="Password"
          />
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
            className="rounded-full bg-white text-black hover:bg-slate-300"
          >
            Sign In
          </Button>
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs>
              <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                Forgot password?
              </Link>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <span onClick={onSwitchToSignUp} className="cursor-pointer"> Don't have an account?Sign up</span>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </>
      </form>
    </Box>

  )
}

export default SignInForm;
```

And the createApi func:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";


export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "postSlice",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:8000/protected",
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPosts: builder.query({
      query: () => "/posts/",
    }),
    addPost: builder.mutation({
      query: (newPost) => ({
        url: "/addPost",
        method: "POST",
        body: newPost,
      }),
    }),
    signUp: builder.mutation({
      query: (signUpData) => ({
        url: "/signup",
        method: "POST",
        body: signUpData,
      })
    }),
    signIn: builder.mutation({
      query: (signInData) => ({
        url: "/signin",
        body: signInData,
      })
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetPostsQuery, useAddPostMutation, useSignUpMutation, useSignInMutation } = apiSlice;
```

I have tried changing the types for signInMutation.